# Understanding Django Pagination: need piece of documentation code explained

Tags: python, django, pagination

I am working with Django's built in *Pagination* and figured out how to functionally use it via the Django Documentation on [Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/pagination/). Despite the fact that I am able to make it work with my app, there is a part of the example logic displayed on the documentations example that I find important to understand well before moving on. They don't explain it that well and I am not finding any other questions on StackOverflow (or the internet) that address it.

***The view file example given for Django Pagination...***

*This example assumes class 'Contact' has already been imported.*

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.shortcuts import render

def listing(request):
    contact_list = Contacts.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        contacts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        contacts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        contacts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'list.html', {'contacts': contacts})
```

***The portion of this code that I would like explained (found in the view file)...***

```
page = request.GET.get('page')
```

What is the significance of `('page')`? I can't figure it out.

***Here is the template file (incase it helps with understanding...***

```
{% for contact in contacts %}
    {# Each "contact" is a Contact model object. #}
    {{ contact.full_name|upper }}<br />
    ...
{% endfor %}

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if contacts.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ contacts.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ contacts.number }} of {{ contacts.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if contacts.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ contacts.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. What is unclear about that line of code?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I don't understand the significance of  `('page')` in the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the links, you are using `page` as the variable to store the page number, for example

```
<a href="?page={{ contacts.previous_page_number }}">
```

In the rendered template, this will be be something like

```
<a href="?page=5">
```

When the use clicks on this link, then `page=5` will be included in the GET parameters for the request. The page number is then fetched in the view with:

```
page = request.GET.get('page')
```

There is nothing special about the chosen variable `page`. The important thing is that the string used in `request.GET.get()` is the same as that used in the template.